# making a substring from string in java without using any string function

Tags: java

I was recently asked this question in an interview(3+ experience). No String function allowed including `String.length`. I was given 5 minutes to write the complete code.

**Example**

```
String ="abcfedbca"
subString = "fed"
```

Actually i asked him to elaborate a little more to which he said "it's easy java implementation what should i elaborate" and on basis of this question only he said my core java is very weak.

Comment: you're going to have to elaborate a bit more if you want anyone to understand what it is your asking...

Comment: Only correct answer: "I'm not a monkey.  Because of that, I'm not interested in reinventing the wheel".

Comment: You didn't explain the question like a 3+ experience guy!

Comment: +1 @DwB This is a terrible interview question, IMO.

Comment: @DwB - This is a just a small test and not one of reusing code.

Comment: Anyone asking this question in an interview deserves the sassiest answer you can come up with. How about this: `public String subString(String str, int i, int j) { p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo " + str + "| cut -c"+i+"-"+j); p.waitFor(); return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())).readLine();}` (*NIX only)

Comment: And the question is.....  what exactly?

Comment: If I got asked this at an interview I'd grill the hell out of the interviewer.  My answer would be something like _I'm afraid I don't know how to do that without at least using one `String` method such as `charAt()`.  The [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#field_summary) for the string method only has 1 field! and it's not a char array.   How would YOU solve it?_

Comment: I don't think there is ANY way to solve this without using any String methods.  By those rules you can't even use `charAt()` or even `getBytes()`.  You can't even subclass it since String is `final`.  If I were asked this, I would stop the interview because obviously I'd be wasting the time of people who think they are much smarter than everyone else.  I do like @HenryKeiter 's approach, though.

Comment: Yeah, technically Henry's solution does not use any functions of String.  ZouZou's works too.  But this is a really stupid question, and the interviewer was insulting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you're question is not very precise and hence your requirements are not very clear.

Simple way :

```
String st = new StringBuilder(s).substring(3,6);
```

Or you can directly construct the new `String` using reflection to get the `char` array:

```
public static String substring(String s, int from, int to){
        Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        char [] tab = (char[])f.get(s);
        f.setAccessible(false);
        return new String(tab, from, to - from);
}
```

---

Those can also be options (note that it works only if the original `String` fits an hexadecimal format) :

```
String s ="abcfedbca";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 16);
bi = bi.and(new BigInteger("16699392")); //0xfed000 in hexa
bi = bi.shiftRight(12);
System.out.println(bi.toString(16));
```

Or more simple :

```
String s ="abcfedbca";
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((int)(Long.parseLong(s, 16) & 16699392) >> 12));
```

---

If you want a more general method, this one might suits your case :

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String s ="abcfedbca";
    System.out.println(substring(s, 2, 5, 9));
}

    public static String substring (String s, int from, int to, int length){
            long shiftLeft = 0;
            long shiftRight = (length - to - 1) * 4;
            for(int i = 0; i < to - from - 1; i++){
                shiftLeft += 15;
                shiftLeft = shiftLeft << 4;
            }
            shiftLeft += 15;
            return Long.toHexString((Long.parseLong(s, 16) & (shiftLeft << shiftRight)) >> shiftRight);
  }
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey The OP is not allowed to use directly String functions _"No String function allowed "_ (even though `StringBuffer` will use them, that's why I said the requirements were not very clear).

Comment: Given that StringBuffer was replaced by StringBuilder almost ten years ago, do you *really* need to use StringBuffer?

Comment: If synchronisation is required yes. If not, you're totally right that using a `StringBuilder` is the way to go.

Comment: If synchronization is required, StringBuffer is still not a good idea because it's not thread safe *between* calls.  i.e. it's only thread safe if you call only one method and if you want toString() that's another method, oops.

Comment: I learn a new thing today =). So the conclusion is : should I always use a `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: IMHO, in the unlikely event you need a thread safe StringBuilder, synchronized/Lock it yourself (which is what you would end up having to do for StringBuffer but it wouldn't be as clear)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `StringBuilder` and call `substring` on it. Don't know whether that'd be allowed.

Here is the other way (although I am ashamed of this solution):

```
String str = "abcfedbca";
int from = 3, length = 3;
java.lang.reflect.Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
valueField.setAccessible(true);
char[] value = (char[]) valueField.get(str);
char[] sub = new char[length];
System.arraycopy(value, from, sub, 0, length);
String substring = new String(sub);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String buff = "abcfedbca";
System.out.println("substring is = " + buff.substring(3, 6));
```

how about this?

Comment: Well `StringBuffer` constructor with a `String` parameter call `super(str.length() + 16);`

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder seems like a cheat to me since it's based on strings.  I'd argue that you have to go down to byte primitives to meet the spirit of the test.  Of course this calls `getBytes` which is technically a String function, so that breaks it also.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String full ="abcfedbca";
    String desiredsubString = "fed";

    byte[] fullByte = full.getBytes();  
    byte[] desiredByte = desiredsubString.getBytes();
    byte[] foundStorage = new byte[desiredByte.length];

    boolean foundStart = false;
    int inserted = 0;

    for (byte b : fullByte) {
        if ( !foundStart && (b == desiredByte[0]) )
        {
            foundStorage[0] = b;
            inserted++;
            foundStart = true;
        }
        else if (foundStart && (inserted < foundStorage.length))
        {
            foundStorage[inserted] = b;
            inserted++;

            if ( inserted >= foundStorage.length )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("These should be equal: " + new String(desiredByte).equals(new String(foundStorage)));

}
```

Comment: I think `String.getBytes` can be considered a "string method".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
    String value = "abcfedbca";
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(value, 16);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    bi = bi.divide(BigInteger.TEN);     
    int val = bi.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(535)).intValue();
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(val);  

    System.out.println(hex);
```

Output: `fed`

Answer (score 0):

How about using a JPasswordField to get the chars:

```
private static String substring(String str, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    return new String(new JPasswordField(str).getPassword(), beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex);
}
```

And the String constructor is not a String method, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String submethod(String data, int firstindex, int lastindex) {
        char[] chars=data.toCharArray();
        char[]charnew= new char [lastindex];
        for(int i=firstindex; i< lastindex;i++) {
            charnew[i]=chars[i];
        }
        return new String(charnew); 
    }
```